# What would happen if antiprotons were studied under the conditions of particle deceleration that they are collected under?

Tags: antimatter, large-hadron-collider

I have not had a very clear understanding of how antiprotons are collected, but I do know that when they collide with matter they explode in a puff of energy.  Or so I have been told.  If the current properties studied of antimatter, being antiprotons, then perhaps they will have different properties in an environment they were collected in?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Antiprotons are normally studied close to where they're produced. Their reactions with normal matter are complex, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilation#Proton-antiproton_annihilation) for some details.

Answer (score 0):

> I do know that when they collide with matter they explode in a puff
>   of energy. Or so I have been told.

Don't trust whoever told that. They told nonsense. There is nothing
like "a puff of energy". Energy is not a *substance*, it's a physical
quantity particles may have in variable amounts.

Collision of an antiproton with "matter" can be better analyzed as a
proton-antiproton annihilation (strictly speaking this isn't the only
possibility - also a neutron-antiproton annihilation is possible, but
it's slightly less simple to analyze).

From proton-antiproton annihilation in vacuum you're left with almost
2 GeV of energy available in COM frame and a lot of possible products
may result: pions (provided total charge remains zero), photons,
kaons, and several other particles, with different probabilities. In
the end (after microseconds) only stable particles will remain, i.e.
photons, electrons, positrons, neutrinos, antineutrinos.